# How to remove " " from text using regex-Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So, I have a text string that I want to remove the "" from.

**Here is my text string:**

```
string= 'Sample this is a string text with "ut" '
```

**Here is the output I want once using a regex expression:**

```
string= 'Sample this is a string text with ut'
```

**Here is my overall code:**

```
import re
string= 'Sample this is a string text with "ut" '
re.sub('" "', '', string)
```

And the output just show the exact text in the string without any changes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why regex? Just `str.replace` will do just fine…

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use `string.replace('"','')`

Comment: Is there any way once the string is replaced and removed, to write to as a csv file?

Comment: You can use the package [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to write it on a csv file.

Comment: ## This removes al "" in a text file

import re
f = open("/home/dir1/ddl2", 'a+', encoding='latin-1')
read_file=f.read()
words= read_file.split()
#string = words.
[i.replace('"', '') for i in words ]

Comment: Thats my code to append the file that I removed the strings from but the output just shows [] and when i refresh the file and open it, the changes arn't made.

Answer (score 5):

If you want just remove all `"` symbols, you can use `str.replace` instead:

`string = string.replace('"', '')`